# Firebase API for moving a tree branch from a collection to another one

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

In my application, I need to move a quite big collection branch to another collection. Currently, I'm using something like that:

```
srcRef
 .startAt(start)
 .endAt(end)
 .once('value', function(snap) {
   destRef.set(snap.exportVal());
 });
```

Obviously, it is quite expensive, so my question is: Why Firebase does not provide a simple API for that? like:

```
srcRef.moveTo(destRef);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the Firebase CLI.**

The Firebase CLI is installed with npm

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then you can execute commands to get and set data:

```
firebase data:get / -f "<my-firebase-app>"
```

I have [a personal project called firebase-dot-files](https://github.com/davideast/firebase-dot-files) that creates bash function to do common operations. One of them is transferring data. After you setup the bash functions you can do the following command:

```
transfer_to dev-firebase staging-firebase
```

[**You can also read this blog post for more information.**](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-11-06-firebase-cli-data-commands.html)

**Firebase CLI as an npm module**

The Firebase CLI can also be [used a node module](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#using-as-a-module). This means you can call your usual CLI methods, but as functions.

Here is a simple data:get command:

```
var client = require('firebase-tools');
client.data.get('/', { firebase: '<my-firebase-db>', output: 'output.json'})
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(2);
  });
```

**To transfer data, you can combine a data:get, with a data:set.**

```
function transfer(path, options) {
  var fromDb = options.fromDb;
  var toDb = options.toDb;
  var output = options.output;
  client.data.get(path, { firebase: fromDb, output: output })
    .then(function(data) {
      return client.data.set(path, output, { firebase: toDb, confirm: true });
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('transferred!');
      process.exit(1);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      process.exit(2);
    });
}

transfer('/', { fromDb: '<from>', toDb: 'to',  output: 'data.json' });
```

Comment: Hi, probably I have poorly explained my issue. With the term server side, I mean firebase. Not my server app.
In other words, I would like to have a "move" API like the "set" to avoid to fetch locally, from my client or server app, data just for moving it from one collection to another.

Comment: You can also run that code locally, but the Firebase CLI is best used from the command line for data transfers. Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, but the data:get command moves the data from Firebase to my app, and the data:set from my app to Firebase. If so, this is my issue because the amount of the data that I have to move is quite big and doesn't make sense, just for moving, transfer data from your service to my client app.

Comment: There is no server side transfer that you're asking for, you can either use the CLI or firebase-import for large data sets. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import

Comment: Probably my question is not a real question, but more a feature request.
This hypothetical "move" API could be very useful and powerful, so please think about it a bit.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are there any other considerations for the answer?

Comment: Cannot find the module firebase-tools when I try to deploy the script