# Find object in Firebase database by value and remove it

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 for managing users and I want to find user by their id, remove them and create a new user.

```
public db: AngularFireDatabase
...
this.db.list('usernames', ref => ref.equalTo(uid)).remove();
```

This removes all users, rather than the one that has the same id.

The database looks like this -
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should split it up. So first get the username you want to delete and then delete the username.

Comment: @AndréKool can i find username when i have only uid ("Sk6I...") ?

Comment: For that take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49460112/4916627) on your other question

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the `TestName` value?. I am not clear about your logic.

Comment: @Hareesh yes, but TestName its a key, and i can't edit this, so i want remove it and create new object

Comment: May be you need to fetch the object you want to delete, then set null in that path.